# Reflection : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, reflection

I try to call a method using reflection.
My object :

```
public class CurrentSearch
{
    public string currentUniverse { get; set; }
    public string currentApplication;
    public string currentUsage;
...
```

My code :

```
CurrentSearch cS = SessionUtils.getCS();
cS.currentUniverse = "lol";         
string methodName = "currentUniverse" ;
var test = typeof(CurrentSearch).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(cS, null);
```

But i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the last line. I've checked cS, it's not null...
What's wrong?
Thx

Comment: You need to use GetProperty, not GetMethod.

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Answer (score 1):

`currentUniverse` is a property, so you need to use `GetProperty`, not `GetMethod`.

```
void Main()
{
    CurrentSearch cs = new CurrentSearch();
    cs.currentUniverse = "lol";         
    string methodName = "currentUniverse" ;
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(CurrentSearch).GetProperty(methodName).GetValue(cs));
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
}

public class CurrentSearch
{
    public string currentUniverse { get; set; }
    public string currentApplication;
    public string currentUsage;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes that was pretty obvious ^^ Thx